# Java - Using code from other files

Tags: java, extends

How exactly is the Java compiler fetching code from other files (using "new" and "extends") without direct reference to those files (by only naming the classes)? is the compiler essentially reading all the Java files in the directory looking for relevant classes to include?

Example:
File 1:

```
public class Person {
  public String name;
 public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

File 2:

```
public class Student extends Person {
...
...
Person you = new Person("foo");
```

Comment: It looks in the same package as the class and the import statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reference a class called `Person` the compiler searches for a file called `Person.class`.

This search is done in each directory specified in the `CLASSPATH` (both the environment variable and the classpath specified in the arguments of `java`).

Note that the compiler first needs to know to what package a class belongs, so you can have two classes with the same name in different packages and still it will find the correct one (the one of the package you imported or that you fully qualified).

So if your class is actually: `com.myorg.Person` it will search in this classpath for a file:

```
com/myorg/Person.class
```

Comment: Note that the *compiler* does this. At runtime, the package name is already resolved (but the JVM classloader still needs to look around a bit in the classpath for the matching class).